# Problem from the Open Latvian Physics Olympiad 2019: "Reactive Reaction"

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, ideal-gas, combustion

> A rockets engine is supplied with a mass $m$ of hydrogen every second and just enough oxygen to burn all of the hydrogen. Determine the thrust force of the engine given that the exhaust openings cross-section area is $S$, the pressure in this area is $p$ and the exiting gas has an absolute temperature $T$.

My first idea was that I have to find the velocity of the exiting gas and then multiply by the mass flow velocity, but I am not sure how to calculate the velocity. My second idea was to relate this to the work that the gas does, but I am not certain how to connect it to the thrust force.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The rate of volume expelled is equal to $\phi=\int \vec v \cdot d\vec s = v \cdot S$ so in 1 second was expelled $v \cdot S$ volume units of gas.

Modeling the hydrogen being an ideal gas we have:

$$pV = \frac{m}{M} R T = pSv  \implies v = \frac{1}{pS}\frac{m}{M} R T  $$

The force is given by $ F = \frac{dm}{dt} \cdot v $ , since $\frac{dm}{dt} = m $ we have:

$$F = \frac{1}{pS}\frac{m^2}{M} R T$$

where M is the molar mass of hydrogen.